# How to convert words of each line as an array separated by '::'and every line as a different array in Python? (which is stored in a file.)

Tags: python

***Input(Which is in a file)strong text:***

```
0::564::1688
1::778::1650
...
```

***Output:***

```
[[0, 564, 1688], [1, 778, 1650], ...]
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: The problem is i can convert lines in a single array which are separated by "space", but i want to convert each line in a different array and save all in a sigle array. The elements of the lines are separated in '::'.

Comment: Then give a [mcve] of the specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming each line is a string:

```
>>> s = """0::564::1688 
1::778::1650"""
>>> [i.split("::") for i in s.split("\n")]
[['0', '564', '1688 '], ['1', '778', '1650']]
```

And if you want to convert the items from string to int as you go through:

```
>>> [[int(x) for x in i.split("::")] for i in s.split("\n")]
[[0, 564, 1688], [1, 778, 1650]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text = """
0::564::1688
1::778::1650
"""

print(text.split('\n'))
lines = text.split('\n')

totalList = []
for line in lines:
    if line.__len__ == 0: continue
    words = line.split('::')

    numberList = []
    for word in words:
        if(word.__len__ == 0): continue
        try:
            print(int(word))
            numberList.append(int(word))
        except:
            print()
    totalList.append(numberList)
```